# A Top Bottom Rule for JMP

Tags: sas, sas-jmp

I need to find the top 20% of a data attribute of a data table in JMP. Excel has a Top-Bottom Rule that help find the same but JMP doesn't quite have it. Is there anyway to figure the top 20% of a column in JMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Col Quantile` function to get the value corresponding to any percentile. Top 20% cutoff would be:

```
Col Quantile(:Calories, 0.8);
```

0.5 would be the median.